# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '59574966\n9'

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm trying to do a google challenge: "find the first 10-digit prime in consecutive digits of e".

I get the error:" ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '59574966\n9'"

This is the relevant code:

```
def getNumber(i, text):
    string = ""
    for x in range(i,i+10):
        string += text[x]

    return string

def init(text):
    i=0
    while(i<2000000-10):
        number = getNumber(i,text)
        if(isPrime(int(number))):
            print(number)
            break;

        i+=1

file = open("C://Users/Name/Desktop/e.txt", 'r')
e = file.read()
init(e)
```

Im loading a file with e to 2 million decimals. isPrime() is a function that I am sure works.

Comment: Have you noticed the newline character inside the string in the error message? Perhaps you need to get rid of (all) newline character(s) before you try parsing a string.

Comment: error message couldn't have been more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
file = open("C://Users/Name/Desktop/e.txt", 'r')
e = file.read()
init(e)
```

You should perhaps do this:

```
with open("C://Users/Name/Desktop/e.txt", 'r') as fd:
    for e in fd:
        e = e.strip()
        if e:
            init(e)
```